# Calculate distance and duration of path in Tableau

Tags: distance, duration, tableau-api

I've a set of data of my vehicle's travel and computed it into a path on the map in Tableau. Due to privacy of the data, I am unable to show the data in here.
I would like to ask or check if anyone is able to get the duration and distance of your points? If it is possible, can anyone help me with such issue? I'm using Tableau to compute my path.

Please advice!

As shown below is an example of such data:

```
x = model
date time as 1 field
long
lat

x,14/1/2018 1:06:12 PM,103.764280,1.331031
x,14/1/2018 1:06:12 PM,103.764253,1.330950
x,14/1/2018 1:06:11 PM,103.764242,1.330870
x,14/1/2018 1:06:11 PM,103.764226,1.330784
x,14/1/2018 1:06:10 PM,103.764210,1.330709
x,14/1/2018 1:06:10 PM,103.764189,1.330645
x,14/1/2018 1:06:09 PM,103.764178,1.330575
x,14/1/2018 1:06:09 PM,103.764172,1.330495
x,14/1/2018 1:06:08 PM,103.764162,1.330414
x,14/1/2018 1:06:08 PM,103.764162,1.330355
x,14/1/2018 1:06:07 PM,103.764156,1.330275
x,14/1/2018 1:06:07 PM,103.764146,1.330205
x,14/1/2018 1:06:06 PM,103.764140,1.330108
x,14/1/2018 1:06:06 PM,103.764124,1.330039
```

Comment: Two separate things to reasearcg: PostGIS and the Haversine formula. If you have SQL server or Oracle, they can substitute for PostGIS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculation of distance using lat long in tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831454/calculation-of-distance-using-lat-long-in-tableau)

Comment: Hi @SamM, The post that you tagged in only asked about calculating distance whereas this post is enquiring on DURATION and DISTANCE.